# Odoo 8: Set client field value from javascript

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

How can I set the value of a field using javascript (on the client)?

In my view's XML-file, I have:

```
<field name="zip" />
<field name="city" class="city" />
```

When the zip changes, I want to do a lookup and set the city (I could do this on the server side with an @api.onchange method, but for performance reasons, I prefer client side).

The lookup works, and I can set the value with:

```
$('span.city input').val(city);
```

This puts the city in the input field, but the client doesn't get aware of the change (for instance, I have a server side onchange method to handle other fields, and this method does not get the new city value).

From what I can find, I should call set_value(city) on the field, but how do I find the right object to call the method on?

Comment: please share your code with as to get more details and give you a hand more properly.

Comment: The code is quite complex (and long), but the basic question is actually very simple: What's the right way to set a field value from javascript?
I know there will be a lot of "that depends", but any hint or example that can bring me closer to a solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at `hr_timesheet_sheet` module in `static/src/js/timesheet.js`.  It will give you a clear view of how you can create field and give it a value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I guess I could use field_manager.set_values(...), but that requires a way to find an object with the field_manager. How can a find an object with a usable field_manager?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. In my zip widget, I find the parent and save the fields list:

```
openerp.zip_widget = function(instance) {
    var _t = instance.web._t,
        _lt = instance.web._lt;
    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;
    var fields; // <-- Variable to keep the field list

    instance.web.form.widgets.add('zip', 'instance.zip_widget.zip_lookup');
    instance.zip_widget.zip_lookup = instance.web.form.FieldChar.extend({
        template: "zip_widget",
        start: function() {
            this._super();
            fields = this.getParent().fields; // <-- Get the field list
        },
```

Now I can set a field value with `fields.city.set_value(...);`